# Does alternating group $A_5$ is a subgroup of $GL(4,\mathbb Z)$?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Does alternating group $A_5$ is a subgroup of $GL(4,\mathbb Z)$? I know $A_5$ has a 4-dimensional complex representation. But how to prove $A_5$ is a subgroup or not of $GL(4, \mathbb Z)$?

In case $GL(4, \mathbb Z)$ has a subgroup isomorphic to $A_5$,  then I would like to know corresponding generators of that subgroup?

I want to know how many subgroups are there in $GL(4, \Bbb Z)$ isomorphic to $A_5$. Is there a unique one?

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any $n$, $S_n$ embeds in $GL(n-1,\Bbb Z)$. Therefore $A_n$ does too.

Consider the vectors $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ where $v_1,\ldots,v_{n-1}$
are the standard unit vectors in $\Bbb Z^{n-1}$ and $v_n=-v_1-\cdots-v_{n-1}$.
By definition $v_1+\cdots+v_n=0$. For each permutation $\tau\in S_n$, there's
a unique endomorphism of $\Bbb Z^{n-1}$ taking each $v_k$ to $v_{\tau(k)}$
(this works due to $v_1+\cdots+v_n=0$). So $S_n$ embeds into $\text{Aut}(
\Bbb Z^{n-1})
=GL(n-1,\Bbb Z)$.

In fact $A_n$ will embed in $SL(n-1,\Bbb Z)$.

Comment: Thanks.  I would like to know corresponding generators of the subgroup of $GL(4, \mathbb Z)$ that is isomorphic to $A_5$  if possible.

Comment: What are your favourite generators of $A_5$? @mathstudent

Comment: Generators of $A_5$: $<(1 2)(3 4), (1 2 3 4 5)>$. Thanks.

Comment: $(1\,2\,3\,4\,5)$ maps to $\pmatrix{0&0&0&-1\\1&0&0&-1\\0&1&0&-1\\0&0&1&-1}$ etc.

Comment: Does $(1\,2\,5\,3\,4)$  maps to $\pmatrix{0&-1&0&1\\1&-1&0&0\\0&-1&1&0\\0&-1&0&0}$ and $(1\,2)(3\,4)$ maps to  $\pmatrix{0&1&0&0\\1&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&1&0}$ ?

Comment: Yes. @mathstudent

Comment: I want to know how many subgroups are there in $GL(4, \Bbb Z)$ isomorphic to $A_5$. Is there a unique one?

Comment: It is a bad idea to ask new questions in comments. It follows from the representation theory over fields that the subgroup is unique up to conjugacy in ${\rm GL}(4,{\mathbb Q})$. In general, conjugacy in ${\rm GL}(4,{\mathbb Z})$ is more difficult to determine. I don't know the answer in this case, but it is certainly known, because the finite subgroups of ${\rm GL}(n,{\mathbb Z})$ have been classified up to about $n=24$.

Comment: I just did a calculation in Magma. There are two ${\rm GL}(4,{\mathbb Z})$-classes of subgroups isomorphic to $A_5$, which are conjugate in ${\rm GL}(4,{\mathbb Q})$. You can get one class from the other by taking the dual i.e. inverting and transposing the matrices. By the way, the third column of your matrix for $(1,2,5,3,4)$ is wrong - it should by $(0\,0\,0\,1)$.